# javascript dialogbox not showing Top data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following javascript function

```
function getPopup1(redirectString) {

        window.showModalDialog(redirectString , null,
'status:no;dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:900px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:1;edge:sunken');
    }
```

The redirect string is redirecting to an .aspx page. The page has a lot of contant so I enabled the scroll bars, but I am getting the page scrolled to end on pageload. 
How can I show the data from top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the page loads in popup , add this to page for scrolling upto top

window.scrollTo(0,0)

Comment: On the page you are getting redirected to .I hope you can modify that page